# System.Timers.Timer creating active threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, threadpool

I am using System.Timers.Timer to process job.
Sample code as below.

```
 private static Timer timer = null;
  timer = new Timer(INTERVAL_MIN * 1000 * 60);
  timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
  timer.start();

 private static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
     Work();
 }
```

after running this job for few hours. 
I got this error

> “There were not enough free threads in the ThreadPool to complete the operation.”

Is this timer thread did not get dispose after use? Do we need to take care of that?

Comment: is you work() tooo much time consuming ???..and you are not creating any more threads after this ...

Comment: yes Work() is doing heavy operations avg time to process is 15 mins.

Comment: ok then try things as I suggested ...I did same thing for my windows service which generates report every day ..

Comment: What is the value of `INTERVAL_MIN`?  We also need a better idea of what `Work()` does.

Comment: INTERVAL_MIN is set to 60, Work is doing calling web service and updating local database

Comment: have you tried solution ..is it worked for you ..let me know if any thing else requried..please do upvote/accept if workes for you

Comment: is that worked for you ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ThreadPool` is primarily intended for brief operations i.e. very small task , so if you do use system.Timer then it consume thread of thread pool. So that is causing of problem.

Because if you `Work()` method, doing too much long operaton like accesing file, web site/webservice or database than this problem will occur.

So solution is to free thread pool thread asap. For this you can do like this:

```
private static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //by doing below it will release thread pool thread and cosume thread where long running option can be performed 
    new Thread (Work).Start();
    //or try with TPL like this 
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
       Work();
    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
```